# How to handle fast moving mouse which doesn't trigger mousemove event

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I am trying to create a simple drag behavior for elements using mouse events and absolute positioning.

I have a `mousemove` event listener for the container div which changes the position of `boxRef` with the help of `clientX` and `clientY` properties of the mouse event.

It works fine when the mouse move is slow, but when it's fast, it just stops,
How can I handle this so that the element does not stop no matter the speed of the mouse move?

```js
const shadowStytle = "10px 10px 12px #888888";

const appRef = document.getElementById('app');
appRef.innerHTML = `<div class="box" id="box"></div>`;

const boxRef = document.getElementById("box");
const xOffset = boxRef.clientWidth / 2;
const yOffset = boxRef.clientHeight / 2;

let selectionLocked = false;

function lockSelection() {
  selectionLocked = true;
  boxRef.style.boxShadow = shadowStytle;
  boxRef.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function unlockSelection() {
  selectionLocked = false;
  boxRef.style.boxShadow = "none";
  boxRef.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}

unlockSelection();

boxRef.addEventListener("mousedown", (arg) => {
  lockSelection();
});

boxRef.addEventListener("mouseup", (arg) => {
  unlockSelection();
});

boxRef.addEventListener("mouseleave", (arg) => {
  if (selectionLocked) {
    selectionLocked = false;
    boxRef.style.boxShadow = "none";
  }
});

appRef.addEventListener("mousemove", (arg) => {
  if (selectionLocked) {
    boxRef.style.left = `${arg.clientX - xOffset}px`;
    boxRef.style.top = `${arg.clientY - yOffset}px`;
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

#### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vanilla-js-simple-drag)

Comment: You can set the `mousemove` event listener function on `window` instead of `appRef`.

Comment: Tried that, still the same behavior

Comment: OMG! Okay I need to sleep I guess, My bad

Comment: I added mouseleave method for some other purpose and removing that works, silly of me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the `mouseleave` on the element. Your problem is that that `mouseleave` fires on the element and it terminates your drag. Instead take advantage of the event bubbling and add your handler to a **sufficiently large parent container** or the `window` itself. Fire up `mouseup` on the window/container **if and only if** it has been **previoulsy activated** by `mousedown`. If you want you can also **remove and re attach the handler on window** on `mousedown` on the element if you want to save some computation. But I left it:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/gd1e93a3/1/

```
const shadowStytle = "10px 10px 12px #888888";

const appRef = document.getElementById('app');
appRef.innerHTML = `<div class="box" id="box"></div>`;

const boxRef = document.getElementById("box");
const xOffset = boxRef.clientWidth / 2;
const yOffset = boxRef.clientHeight / 2;

let selectionLocked = false;

function lockSelection() {
  selectionLocked = true;
  boxRef.style.boxShadow = shadowStytle;
  boxRef.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function unlockSelection() {
  selectionLocked = false;
  boxRef.style.boxShadow = "none";
  boxRef.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}

unlockSelection();

boxRef.addEventListener("mousedown", (arg) => {
  lockSelection();
});

window.addEventListener("mouseup", (arg) => {
  selectionLocked && unlockSelection();
});

boxRef.addEventListener("mouseleave", (arg) => {
  /*if (selectionLocked) {
    selectionLocked = false;
    boxRef.style.boxShadow = "none";
  }*/
});

window.addEventListener("mousemove", (arg) => {
  if (selectionLocked) {
    boxRef.style.left = `${arg.clientX - xOffset}px`;
    boxRef.style.top = `${arg.clientY - yOffset}px`;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help